# Tree json "menu" with nested items : check the "branch"

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this JSON tree view that represents a menu :

```
var menus = [
  {
    label : "1",
    items: [
      {
        label : "1.1"
      },
      {
        label : "1.2",
        items : [
          {
            label : "1.2.1"
          },
          {
            label : "1.2.2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label : "1.3"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    label : "2"
  }
]
```

I want to mutate this JSON by adding for each item a *selected* property. This property, a boolean, will be set to **true** if the *label* is the right one or *this is the tricky part* if the descendant is the right one.
For instance, if I'm looking for *label* `1.2`, all labels 1 and 1.2 will be selected. So I will get this JSON :

```
var menus = [
  {
    label : "1",
    selected : true,
    items: [
      {
        label : "1.1"
        selected : false
      },
      {
        label : "1.2",
        selected : true,
        items : [
          {
            label : "1.2.1"
            selected : false
          },
          {
            label : "1.2.2",
            selected : false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label : "1.3",
        selected : false
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    label : "2",
    selected : false
  }
]
```

the `selected : false` is not necessary.
Lodash is OK for me;)!

Any suggestions?

edit : where I am ! --> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XGoXjM?editors=0010

edit 2 : finding elements must not be based on the way I wrote the labels. The labels can be any string... Sorry...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution uses a for loop to iterate recursively the menu items and their children. If an item is `selected`, it adds `selected: true` to the item and it's parents:

```js
const selectMenuItems = menus => selectedLabel => {  
  const internal = arr => {
    let selected = false

    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      const item = arr[i]
      const childrenSelected = !!item.items && internal(item.items)
      item.selected = childrenSelected || item.label === selectedLabel
      selected = selected || item.selected
    }
    
    return selected
  }
  
  internal(menus)
  
  return menus
}

const menus = [{"label":"1","items":[{"label":"1.1"},{"label":"1.2","items":[{"label":"1.2.1"},{"label":"1.2.2"}]},{"label":"1.3"}]},{"label":"2"}]

const menuSelector = selectMenuItems(menus)

const result = menuSelector('1.2')

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thanks a lot ;) ! I have just changed the *for loop* with a *arr.forEach*

Answer (score 0):

You can use some recursive approach to implement this.

```
let str = '1.2.1';


function checkItem(arr, strArr) {
  // iterate over the array
  arr.forEach((obj) => {
    // set selected property based on matching every digit in label in same order
    // if digits would be single then you can use startsWith and no need to split string
    obj.selected = obj.label.split('.').every((it, i) => it === strArr[i]);
    // if nested item is there then call recursively
    obj.items && checkItem(obj.items, strArr);
  });
  return arr;
}

checkItem(menus, str.split('.'));
```

```js
var menus = [{
    label: "1",
    items: [{
        label: "1.1"
      },
      {
        label: "1.2",
        items: [{
            label: "1.2.1"
          },
          {
            label: "1.2.2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: "1.3"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "2"
  }
];



let str = '1.2.1';


function checkItem(arr, strArr) {
  arr.forEach((obj) => {
    obj.selected = obj.label.split('.').every((it, i) => it === strArr[i]);
    obj.items && checkItem(obj.items, strArr);
  });
  return arr;
}

checkItem(menus, str.split('.'));


console.log(menus);
```

---

**UPADATE :** Since you want to update selected property completely independent of label you can do something like follows. I assume you want to 
update based on position in the array.

```
let str = '1.2.1';


function checkItem(arr, prefixArray, strArr) {
  // iterate over the array
  arr.forEach((obj, i) => {
    // generate new prefix array for checking
    let pa = [...prefixArray, i + 1];
    // compare prefix array with the string array to check matches
    obj.selected = pa.every((it, i) => it == strArr[i]);
    // if items defined do it recursively
    obj.items && checkItem(obj.items, pa, strArr);
  });
  return arr;
}

checkItem(menus,[], str.split('.'));
```

```js
var menus = [{
    label: "1",
    items: [{
        label: "1.1"
      },
      {
        label: "1.2",
        items: [{
            label: "1.2.1"
          },
          {
            label: "1.2.2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        label: "1.3"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "2"
  }
];



let str = '1.2.1';


function checkItem(arr, prefixArray, strArr) {
  arr.forEach((obj, i) => {
    let pa = [...prefixArray, i + 1];
    obj.selected = pa.every((it, i) => it == strArr[i]);
    obj.items && checkItem(obj.items, pa, strArr);
  });
  return arr;
}

checkItem(menus,[], str.split('.'));


console.log(menus);
```

Comment: That is nice ! Thanks ! But.... my labeling was only for the example : labels can be any string...

Answer (score 0):

I would simply check labels this way:

```js
var menus = [{
        label: "1",
        items: [{
                label: "1.1"
            },
            {
                label: "1.2",
                items: [{
                        label: "1.2.1"
                    },
                    {
                        label: "1.2.2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                label: "1.3"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        label: "2"
    }
];

var checkSelected = function(items, search) {
    for (var key in items) {
        items[key].selected = search.startsWith(items[key].label) && items[key].label.length<=search.length;
        if (items[key].items) {
            checkSelected(items[key].items, search);
        };
    };
};

var test = "1.2";
checkSelected(menus, test);
console.log(menus);
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7e3dfn0/).

> The startsWith() method determines whether a string begins with the
>   characters of a specified string, returning true or false as
>   appropriate.

[quoted from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

Comment: there may be issue when there is 2 digit (startsWith)...... eg: when u r searching for  `1.11`, `1.21` and where label is  `1.1`, `1.2`

Comment: Thanks Pranav, updated the answer, so there will be no issues.

Comment: I have edited my question (edit 2) : *The labels can be any string...* Sorry

Comment: @skobaljic :looks fine now :)